# Center form on screen or on parent

Tags: vb.net

Since built in functionality for positioning forms in VB.NET are not always suitable to use I try to make my sub to do that.

But I missed something...

```
Public Sub form_center(ByVal frm As Form, Optional ByVal parent As Form = Nothing)

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim r As Rectangle

    If Not parent Is Nothing Then
        r = parent.ClientRectangle
        x = r.Width - frm.Width + parent.Left
        y = r.Height - frm.Height + parent.Top
    Else
        r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
        x = r.Width - frm.Width
        y = r.Height - frm.Height
    End If

    x = CInt(x / 2)
    y = CInt(y / 2)

    frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
    frm.Location = New Point(x, y)
End Sub
```

How to get this sub to place form correctly in the middle of the screen or other form if is defined?

Comment: how is that more suitable or easier than the native CenterScreen or CenterParent?  You need to check that the parent form is actually larger than the form you are trying to show...

Comment: It is suitable because I can place form to position in _Load handler or later and I haven't to think about setting start position to "Manual".

Comment: Also, parent form shouldn't be a real parent, can be any kind of form!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The code is just wrong.  It is also essential that this code runs late enough, the constructor is too early.  Be sure to call it from the Load event, at that time the form is properly auto-scaled and adjusted for the user's preferences, the StartPosition property no longer matters then.  Fix:

```
Public Shared Sub CenterForm(ByVal frm As Form, Optional ByVal parent As Form = Nothing)
    '' Note: call this from frm's Load event!
    Dim r As Rectangle
    If parent IsNot Nothing Then
        r = parent.RectangleToScreen(parent.ClientRectangle)
    Else
        r = Screen.FromPoint(frm.Location).WorkingArea
    End If

    Dim x = r.Left + (r.Width - frm.Width) \ 2
    Dim y = r.Top + (r.Height - frm.Height) \ 2
    frm.Location = New Point(x, y)
End Sub
```

Incidentally, one of the very few reasons to actually implement the Load event handler.

Comment: Hi Hans. This code centers a form to the screen but not properly to "parent" form. form_center(Me, Me.Owner) places new form too left and too up from Owner.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what should be. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 50):

I know this is an old post and this doesn't directly answer the question, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this thread, centering a form can be done simply without requiring you to write your own procedure.

The  **`System.Windows.Forms.Form.CenterToScreen()`** and **`System.Windows.Forms.Form.CenterToParent()`** allow you to center the a form in reference to the screen or in reference to the parent form depending on which one you need.

One thing to note is that these procedures **MUST** be called before the form is loaded. It is best to call them in the form_load event handler.

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
  Private Sub Settings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Me.CenterToScreen()

    'or you can use 

    Me.CenterToParent()

End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing as OP, and found this. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Cleaner, easier and faster. Works gr8t!

Comment: AWESOME! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 11):

This might also be of use:

```
    myForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
    myForm.ShowDialog()
```

You can also use FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem with `StartPosition = CenterParent` not working. I solved it calling the form with `.ShowDialog()` instead of `.Show()`:

```
' first you should set your form's Start Position as Center Parent
Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button.Click
    MyForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggeling with this today. After reading the documentation, I learned 1. [that you cannot call the CenterToParent method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.centertoparent?view=net-5.0), 2. [that you need to set the .StartingPosition Property of the form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.startposition?view=net-5.0), and 3. that "This property should be set before the form is shown, You can set this property before you call the Show or ShowDialog method".
So how I fixed it. is by placing the code into the sub that instantiates the childform, on the parent form, as shown below.

```
Private Sub btnItemCategories_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnItemCategories.Click
    Dim objItemCategories As New frmItemCategories
    objItemCategories.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
    objItemCategories.ShowDialog(Me)
End Sub
```