# Center parent form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get a form to center the parent. I have done lots of 'googling' and none if it has worked.

The issue is. When I have a form set to "Center Parent Form" it will work, unless the parent form is moved from the original starting location.

Example: Parent form starts top left of screen. I move it to center screen. I then preform and action to have a popup window, that window gets Centered to the original location of the parent form in the top left. Not the current one. 
Visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/byaSd.jpg

I have set the form properties to be 'Center Parent' as well as

```
Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
```

Comment: Please show the code you use to show the second form.

Comment: @MarkHall `popup.Show()`

Comment: try `popup.Show(Me)`

Comment: Kind of... I will take some screenshots to show what its doing, Very hard to explain

Comment: @MarkHall http://imgur.com/a/jGBfP as you can see it moves a bit depending where the main form is located

Comment: Where is the `StartPosition` being set?  It is usually set in the designer file as part of the InitializeComponent method.  Whether set in the designer or some other bit of code you need to set it before the call to .Show or .ShowDialog.  Also, as MarkHall pointed out, you need to tell it what "parent" means - typically by passing the parent in the .Show parameters.

Comment: That doesn't sound like the normal behaviour.  Can you provide a set of instructions that we can follow to try to reproduce the issue and compare behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In which class and method are you setting the `Me.StartPosition` property?

Have you seen this Stackoverflow answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199106/1337635

***UPDATE***
You need to do two things to get this to work:-

1. As per @mark-hall, you need to show the form and pass in the parent:-

   `Dim child As frmChild`

   `child = New frmChild()`

   `child.Show(Me)    'Explicitly declare the parent`
2. As per the above answer I referenced, in the `Load` event of the child form, you need to call `Me.CenterToParent()`

Comment: Used the code from the first post by user973238. It works, unless I move the base form, then it sticks to the original spot. EDIT: I see how it works, it centers screen, not form.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate the problem. Try adding the `Shown` EventHandler to your popup form. If you then assign the owner to the Form when you show it you should be able to position your form in the Handler, something like this. Be aware if you move the Owning Form the popup Form will not change.

Make sure you Show the Form using `Show(Me)` or else `Owner` will not be populated.

```
Public Class popup
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        BackColor = Color.LightBlue 'So I can see it

    End Sub

    Private Sub popup_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        Left = (Owner.Width / 2 - Width / 2) + Owner.Left
        Top = (Owner.Height / 2 - Height / 2) + Owner.Top

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Forgive me, but what do you mean by assigning the owner? Or how would I go about doing that.

Comment: when you show the form use the syntax that I mentioned `YourFormNameHere.Show(Me)`.

Comment: Ok, Base Form I have 
`Me.CenterToScreen()` on Load.  
And `popup.Show(Me)` on click.
Then on popup form I have your code on Shown. No luck tho, I am sure I am missing something

Comment: Make sure that the Shown event is being triggered. I also called this class popup, you will need to create an instance of the popup form and show that. Something like `Dim myPopup as popup = new popup()` then you would use `myPopup.Show(Me)` if you don't do it this way you will be using the default instance of the popup form.