# Which form opened another form

Tags: vb.net

In my application, there is a particular form that is used to input a date range. This form is called from many locations in the application and from several forms using a simple `TestDates.ShowDialog()` call

I would like to center the said form on the form that called it (its parent). I however cannot figure out how to determine which form originated the call.

The code below has all the possibilities (as a test) that I can think of ie Parent, Owner, MidParent and they all are nothing.

```
Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Owner.Location.X + (Me.MdiParent.Bounds.Width - Me.Width) \ 2, Me.Parent.Location.Y + (MdiParent.Bounds.Height - Me.Height) \ 2)
```

I cant use startposition.Centerparent as the application undergoes some sizing adjustment and the call does not center the testdate form properly in high DPI.

Is there another way to determine the originator of the call that opened the test dates form?

Comment: There is an argument to ShowDialog you're missing that is *much* easier than doing it manually.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31063964/center-parent-form/31064614#31064614

Comment: thanks for the heads up, the answer is to use TestDates.showDialog(Me), its the Me or the Form that supplies the Owner of the opened form.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out, in order to 'supply' the Owner, or the Form that opened the Newform is to ensure that you use NewForm.load(Me). Which will then identify the ME or the form that made the call. That is what I was missing in my code

So it looks like this now

```
Me.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(Me.Owner.Location.X + (Me.Owner.Bounds.Width - Me.Width) \ 2, Me.Owner.Location.Y + (Me.Owner.Bounds.Height - Me.Height) \ 2)
```

The above when place in the form.load or Form.shown sub on the new form will center the new form on the old form providing the call is made like this `NewForm.Show(Me)`