# How do I position a form to be top centre of the screen in VB

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms, position

I want to have a toolbar style application that will sit at the top of the screen - in the middle but unsure on what code to use to make this happen automatically.

There is no customer position option - like there was back in the old VB days. Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can set the form's `Location` property in the form's `Load` event handler: `Me.Location = New Point((Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width) \ 2, 0)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center form on screen or on parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392083/center-form-on-screen-or-on-parent)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in Form_Load:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    CenterToScreen()
    Top = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Dave - Thank you for your answwer, it worked. Pretty simple. I'm new to all of this.