# Centering a RichTextBox in Visual Basic

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I'm writing a program in Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2019.
I want to put a Multi Line RichTextBox in the center of a Form.
I want the RichTextBox to be in the center of the Form for any
computer the program is run on.
In other words I want the RichTextBox in the center of the screen
on any computer screen.

Comment: Look at the following answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557036/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557036/6630084). Your question more related to centering the application form, not to the `RichTextBox` itself. To center your control inside the form set the `Anchor` property to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the form load event handler:

```
CenterToScreen()
Top = 0
```

Also, make sure the RichTextBox is maximized or centered in the form.